# How to render text and components at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to write a react component that gets any text string, match: urls, emails, mentions, tags and returns Btn components instead of them. There is a snippet of code:

```
var StringParser = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      type: 'div'
    }
  }

  , callbackMention: function(username) {
    console.log('Mention is ' + username)
  } 

  , callbackTag: function(tag) {
    console.log('Tag is ' + tag)
  } 

  , render: function() {
    var self = this
    var str = self.props.text
    var re = [
      "\\b((?:https?|ftp)://[^\\s\"'<>]+)\\b",
      "\\b(www\\.[^\\s\"'<>]+)\\b",
      "\\b(\\w[\\w.+-]*@[\\w.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,6})\\b", 
      "#([a-z0-9]+)",
      "@([a-z0-9]+)"]
    re = new RegExp(re.join('|'), "gi") 
    var parse = str.replace(re, function(parsed, url, www, email, tag, username){
      if(url && self.props.url) return ( <Btn callback={self.callbackTag} text={url}/> )
      if(www && self.props.url) return ( <Btn callback={self.callbackTag} text={www}/> )
      if(email && self.props.email) return ( <Btn callback={self.callbackTag} text={email}/> )
      if(tag && self.props.tag) return ( <Btn callback={self.callbackTag} text={tag}/> )
      if(username && self.props.username) return ( <Btn callback={self.callbackMention} text={username}/> )
      return parsed
    })
    console.log(parse)
    return React.createElement(self.props.type, self.props, parse)
  }
})
```

but when I try to parse such line:

```
 <StringParser className="stringy" text={'hello www.bar.com#123 mail me at foo@d.com twitler me #123 @user123'}/>
```

I get:

```
hello [object Object] mail me at [object Object] twitler me [object Object] [object Object]
```

I have two ways to solve a problem:

1. Instead of Btn component return 'span class="..." onClick="this.callbackTag">...'
2. Convert objects into string. How?

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) coerces whatever you return from a given replacer function to String (hence the `'[object Object]'` you're seeing), but you want to retain the React components you're creating as objects to be rendered by React.

You could write your own replace function which returns an Array rather than a String:

```
function replaceToArray(text, re, replacer, thisArg) {
  var lastIndex = 0
  var match
  var result = []

  while ((match = re.exec(text)) !== null) {
    // Text preceding the match
    if (lastIndex !== match.index) {
      result.push(text.slice(lastIndex, match.index))
    }
    result.push(replacer.apply(thisArg, match))
    lastIndex = re.lastIndex
  }
  // Text following the last match
  if (lastIndex !== text.length - 1) {
    result.push(text.slice(lastIndex))
  }

  return result
}
```

Then this should work:

```
var parse = replaceToArray(str, re, function(parsed, url, www, email, tag, username) {
  if (url && this.props.url) return <Btn callback={this.callbackTag} text={url}/>
  if (www && this.props.url) return <Btn callback={this.callbackTag} text={www}/>
  if (email && this.props.email) return <Btn callback={this.callbackTag} text={email}/>
  if (tag && this.props.tag) return <Btn callback={this.callbackTag} text={tag}/>
  if (username && this.props.username) return <Btn callback={this.callbackMention} text={username}/>
  return parsed
}, this)
```

**Note:** Since you're returning an Array with components in it, React will complain if they don't have a unique`key` prop it can use to identify them on subsequent renders, so you'll need to provide one in the components you're generating if you want to silence that warning.

Comment: +1; just want to add, since it's easy to forget sometimes, that JSX is not HTML, and typing `<Btn />` does not generate a string. It's an object.

Answer (score 0):

To convert them to strings you could use [renderToString](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendertostring), or renderToStaticMarkup,  but you might lose the ability to callback. This is how react-intl handles [html in strings](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/master/src/components/html-message.js)